# Display stored procedure using a sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to display the entire code in a stored procedure using SQL query when i have the name and db of the stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

`sp_helptext` seems like it might do the trick for you.  Syntax [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/25/sql-server-stored-procedure-to-display-code-text-of-stored-procedure-trigger-view-or-object/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT [definition]
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.YourStoredProcNameHere')
```

Works in SQL Server 2005 and newer.

Comment: Thank you, but this sp_helptext spname helped me..:)